# Token concatenation using ## gives "not a valid preprocessing token"

Tags: c

The following code gives error:

"pasting "f32_Q31" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token"

```
#define INIT_Q(N, name, val) \
    name.value = f32_Q##N##(val);

#define f32_Q31(x)      f32_Q(31,x)
INIT_Q31(name, val)     INIT_Q(31, name, val)
INIT_Q25(name, val)     INIT_Q(25, name, val)
```

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you by chance mean `name.value = f32_Q##N(val);`? The version above doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Changed it, see below.

Comment: @Danijel : you seem to have forgotten `#define`s at the starts of the last two lines.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That solves the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `f32_Q31(` is not a single token, but two. The `(` is a token in and of itself. The result of concatenation must be a *single* valid token.

If your intent is to initialize `name.value` with the expansion of another macro, the following will do:

```
#define INIT_Q(N, name, val) \
    name.value = f32_Q##N(val);
```

The macro name is what must be a valid token, not the whole expression.

---

As **Sander De Dycker** pointed out, you seem to have also omitted the `define` from your last two macro definitions:

```
#define INIT_Q31(name, val)     INIT_Q(31, name, val)
#define INIT_Q25(name, val)     INIT_Q(25, name, val)
```

Comment: Changed it. Now it points to INIT_Q31( and says: "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token".

Comment: @Danijel - When your code is reduced to just the mentioned problem, it's solved (http://ideone.com/zJTK2o). If you have another issue, it's not in what you've shown or related to my fix suggestion. The fix only allowed the compiler to stumble across the next problem.

Comment: @Danijel Does your C compiler know about constructors and destructors? That's pretty unusual. Perhaps you are using another language with a name that contains the capital letter C?

Comment: I am using C++ compiler (mingw g++), yes.

Comment: Adding a `#define` and removing `##` on the right side solves the issue, thanks all.

Comment: @Danijel (1) Tag your question C++, not C (2) Consider not using macros in C++.